# How to save TableGrob object to file

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have a TableGrob object:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
d <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=11:15)
p <- ggplot(d) + aes(x=x,y=y) + geom_point()
g <- arrangeGrob(p,p,ncol=1)
```

`plot(g)` will expectedly plot two identical plots arranged in one column.

When I try to save it to file:

```
ggsave('a.pdf',g)
```

all I get is an empty file `a.pdf` and the following output:

```
Saving 7 x 7 in image
TableGrob (2 x 1) "arrange": 2 grobs
  z     cells    name           grob
1 1 (1-1,1-1) arrange gtable[layout]
2 2 (2-2,1-1) arrange gtable[layout]
```

My question is: **how to save a TableGrob object to a pdf file?**

Just in case, here is the `sessionInfo()` output:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  grid      methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gridExtra_2.2.1 dplyr_0.4.3     plyr_1.8.3      ggplot2_2.1.0   reshape_0.8.5   gdata_2.17.0    lattice_0.20-33

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5        gtools_3.5.0       digest_0.6.9       assertthat_0.1     R6_2.1.2           gtable_0.2.0      
 [7] DBI_0.4-1          magrittr_1.5       scales_0.4.0       labeling_0.3       RColorBrewer_1.1-2 tools_3.3.0       
[13] munsell_0.4.3      parallel_3.3.0     colorspace_1.2-6
```

Comment: @baptiste, any chance you have an answer?

Comment: please see my comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird...I get the expected output from `ggsave('a.pdf', g)`.
Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere..? In general, I've used this hack to save a tableGrob to PDF:

```
qplot(1:10, 1:10, geom = "blank") + theme_bw() + 
  theme(line = element_blank()) + 
  annotation_custom(grob = tableGrob(d), xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf)
```

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gridExtra_2.2.1 ggplot2_2.1.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.4.0     plyr_1.8.4      
 [5] tools_3.3.0      gtable_0.2.0     Rcpp_0.12.5      grid_3.3.0      
 [9] munsell_0.4.3    tcltk_3.3.0
```

Comment: I found the answer. The issue was that I had the `ggsave` function  in my `~/.Rdata` file (don't ask how it happened). Once I removed `~/.Rdata`, the problem disappeared.

Comment: can we clarify a few things for posterity? First, we should close the question as it was a typo / local issue not likely to be found again. Second, `plot()` is never a good way to display a gtable (use grid.draw, plot.gtable is meant for debugging only). Third, this answer is not really an answer, more of a comment. And there is really no need to embed a table in a ggplot to save it to pdf!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I agree to close the question, and I would like to thank @fanli one more time for heading me in the right direction.

Comment: @baptiste, could you please explain what you meant in the last remark?

Comment: @MaratTalipov usually "I cannot reproduce this" is given as a comment, because it doesn't solve the problem by itself. And the proposed workaround should not be necessary, since as pointed out, there is no real issue.

Comment: @baptiste, Sorry for the confusion, I was asking to clarify this phrase "And there is really no need to embed a table in a ggplot to save it to pdf!"

Comment: Yes, I'm curious about this as well. How do you (otherwise) write a table to pdf?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really make sense of the question or its follow-ups, but perhaps this will make sense to someone

```
library(gridExtra)
d <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=11:15)
g <- tableGrob(d)
ggplot2::ggsave('a.pdf',g)
```

[image]